# Convert into void*

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, void

how can I convert any object of my own class convert into pointer to void?

```
MyClass obj;
(void*)obj; // Fail
```

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @bo-persson I have a structure which can store an additional info inside it by passing a `void*` data.

Comment: one you wrote or inherited? if former - why-o-why?

Comment: @nim That structure is from own library, I can't modify it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
MyClass obj;
void *p;

p = (void*)&obj; // Explicit cast.
// or:
p = &obj; // Implicit cast, as every pointer is compatible with void *
```

But beware ! `obj` is allocated on the stack this way, as soon as you leave the function the pointer becomes invalid.

**Edit**: Updated to show that *in this case* an explicit cast is not necessary since every pointer is compatible with a void pointer.

Comment: So, why is everyone _explicitly_ casting to void*?

Comment: Can I use `shared_ptr` for to controll the life?

Comment: @Cwan: Reflex. When I do some casting I almost always do it explicitly. Have updated my answer.

Comment: @Ockonal: No idea, my C++ is very, very rusty.

Comment: @DarkDust: Not **every** pointer is "compatible" (you mean, implicitly convertible) to `void*`. For example you can't convert a `const char*` to `void*` without a `const_cast`

Comment: Terminology: a cast is an explicit conversion. An implicit conversion is not a cast.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, I should probably have been more precise and said "explicitly converting to void* using a cast".

Answer (score 6):

You cant convert a non-pointer to `void*`. You need to convert the pointer to your object to `void*`

```
(void*)(&obj); //no need to cast explicitly.
```

***that conversion is implicit***

```
void* p = &obj; //OK
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use the address, you can convert it to a `void` pointer.

```
MyClass obj;
void *ptr = (void*)&obj; // Success!
```

Answer (score 1):

To do something which has any chance of being meaningful, first you have to take the address of an object, obtaining a pointer value; then cast the pointer.

```
MyClass obj;
MyClass * pObj = &obj;
void * pVoidObj = (void*)pObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

i beleive you could only convert a pointer to an object to a pointer to void ???

Perhaps: `(void*)(&obj)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the technical answers: Assert, that you avoid multiple inheritance or else you don't assign the address of super-class interfaces to a void*, for they will not be unique! E.g.

```
class S1 { int u; };
class S2 { int v; };
class MyClass : public S1, public S2 {};

MyClass obj;
S2* s2 = &obj;
void * p1 = &obj;
void * p2 = s2;
```

Here p1 and p2 (==s2) will be different, because the S2 instance in C has an address offset.